# How to copy all the words in a paragraph and add each word # on delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7, delphi-xe5

Using Delphi 7, if I have some text like that shown in the lefthand window below, how could I extract all the words and punctuation in a paragraph and copy them to another window like that on the right, followed by a  #?

[image]

Comment: What part of this task are you struggling with? What version of Delphi? Your tags are confusing.

Comment: study delphi 7 or delphi xe5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you need what's called a "tokeniser" or "lexer".

D7 comes with one built-in, in the Classes unit, misleadingly called TParser (misleadingly because parsing normally means the "grammatical analysis" step which may follow the tokenisation of the text, as happens f.i. in the operation of a compiler).

Anyway, iirc, Delphi's TParser was intended to do things like process the text of DFM files, so will not necessarily split the text up exactly as you want, but it's a start.  For example, when it tokenises ":=", it will return the ":" and "=" as two separate tokens, but, of course you are free to join them up again when NextToken/TokenString return these in succession.  Btw, there are several alternative ways of implementing a tokeniser using classes in the freeware Jedi JCL and JVCL libraries, f.i.

If the text window on the left of your q is in your own app, code like the following
may do what you want:

```
procedure TForm1.Tokenise;
var
  SS : TStringStream;
  TokenText : String;
  Parser : TParser;
begin
  SS := TStringStream.Create(Memo1.Lines.Text);
  Parser := TParser.Create(SS);

  try
    while Parser.Token <> #0 do begin
      TokenText :=  Parser.TokenString;
      Memo2.Lines.Add(TokenText + '#');
      Parser.NextToken;
    end;
  finally
    Parser.Free;
    SS.Free;
  end;

end;
```

If the text window is in another app, you would need a method of retrieving the text from it, too, of course.

Comment: Glad if it helps.  If it does, please feel free to "accept" the answer by clicking the "tick" icon on the left ...

Comment: I'm curious why the downvote? I'm the upvote anyway.

Comment: Thanks @JerryDodge.  Perhaps someone will tell us.  Maybe the -1 was somehow out of irritation with the OP's later q, now deleted.